# Latex command problem

Tags: math-mode

I'm not sure what the correct command is.

I tried this  `$^\mathbb{N}|mathbb{Q}$` But it doesn't look correct.  How do I fix the error?

Comment: This is a very unclear question. We don't know what your PDF looks like, nor do we know what you intend it to look like! Please upload some images.

Comment: From what I can tell, that `|` should really be a `\ `.

Comment: @1010011010: Oh my... yes, of course ... how could I overlook that...

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very unclear but perhaps you are looking for

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

 $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Q}$ 

\end{document}
```